# Is it possible to switch AngularJS's internationalization language on the fly at runtime?

Tags: angularjs, internationalization

Is it possible to switch between `i18n/angular-locale_en-us.js` and `i18n/angular-locale_de-de.js`, for example, at runtime and have all date, currency and number filters update instantly? (Instantly means after the new locale file loaded of course).

Thank you.

Comment: Also, checkout http://pascalprecht.github.io/angular-translate/

Comment: I'm using that, but it doesn't have number, currency or date formatters.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I managed to do this using this module: https://github.com/lgalfaso/angular-dynamic-locale

Works perfectly!

Answer (score 1):

It is and it is not. If you stick with built-in solution for i18n (which to be honest is somewhat broken), there is no way to switch locales. You may dynamically load the desired script, but once Angular resolve all bindings it is already too late (it won't use newly loaded locale script).

To overcome this problem, you may want to create your own filters and use something like [Globalize](https://github.com/jquery/globalize) or [iLib](http://ilibjavascriptl.sourceforge.net/) to do the formatting.